# Convergent or Divergent Series? $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\sqrt[n+1]{10}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need to find whether this series is convergent or divergent:
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{ n + 1}}
{\,\sqrt[n + 1]{\, 10\, }\, }
$$

(1) Alternating series test does not provide any additional information since $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt[n+1]{10}} = 1$ and not $0$. A ratio test with its larger series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt[n+1]{10}}$ results in $1$ meaning its inconclusive. Can someone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Alternating series does not have a no conclusion option, it can readily give you divergence, but the limit is the best way to go as the answer says.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general term of the series is not converging to $0$: as you mentioned it, its absolute value converges to one.

Therefore the series diverges.

Answer (score 1):

An explicit, crude bound on the terms.

If
$(1+a)^{1/n} = 1+b$,
then,
by Bernoulli's inequality,
$1+a
=(1+b)^n
\ge 1+nb
$
so
$b
\le a/n
$
so
$(1+a)^{1/n}
\le 1+a/n
$.

Therefore
$\dfrac1{(1+a)^{1/n}}
\ge \dfrac1{1+a/n}
=\dfrac{n}{n+a}
=1-\dfrac{a}{n+a}
\to 1
$
as
$n \to \infty$.

In this case,
$\dfrac1{10^{1/n}}
\ge 1-\dfrac{9}{n+9}
$.