# What test should I use for showing the series is divergent or convergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

[image: Image right here, don't know why I am not allow to embed image][>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuhFU.png)

> Find *all* convergent infinite series from the following:
>
> - $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{5^nn!}{(2n)!}$
> - $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\sqrt[n]4}$
> - $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos n}{n^2+e^{-n}}$
> - $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{3}{(2+\frac1n)^{2n}}$

I am doing some exercise about finding out all the convergent series.

It is not hard to find out (i) and (iv) is convergent by ratio test and root test respectively

I was struggling about how to show if  (ii) and (iii) is convergent or not.

For (ii) I was thinking about using divergence test to show the (ii) is oscillating due to $(-1)^{n+1}$ and I want to know if it is a correct approach?

But for (iii) I really have no idea on using what kind of test.

Pls help!!!!

[image: Image right here, don't know why I am not allow to embed image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: @geetha290krm I dont think (ii) can use Alternating test as it is increasing

Comment: Embedded images cannot be searched

Comment: For (ii): If $a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt[n]4}$, what is the limit $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}|a_n|=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac1{\sqrt[n]4}$? 
You can have a look at this related question: [Convergent or Divergent Series? $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\sqrt[n+1]{10}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3771169) (I found it [using Approach Zero](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum%5Climits_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%5Cinfty%20%5Cfrac%7B(-1)%5E%7Bn%2B1%7D%7D%7B%5Csqrt%5Bn%5D4%7D%24&p=1).)

Comment: ii) does not converge because the general term does not tend to $0$ and and iii) is convergent by comparison with $\sum \frac 1 {n^{2}}$

Comment: @MartinSleziak  Even I know the limit tends to 1 but I am not understand why absolute value is added to it ?

Comment: OH ok I got it now, thx for the help. Highly appreciate it!!

Comment: The absolute value does not matter that much - looking either at $a_n$ or at $|a_n|$ you get that the necessary condition for convergence of the series is not fulfilled. I added the absolute values simply because the limit $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}|a_n|$ exists. (And the limit of $a_n$ - without the absolute value - does not exist.)

Comment: In case it might help you to find some existing posts related to your questions: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was basically said in comments - but it is probably good to have an answer summarizing the comments.

---

In the second series you have $a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt[n]4}$. The series $\sum a_n$ does not converge, since it does not fulfill the necessary condition $a_n\to 0$. In fact, we have $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}|a_n|=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac1{\sqrt[n]4}=1$.
Here is a similar older question: [Convergent or Divergent Series? $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\sqrt[n+1]{10}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3771169)

---

The third series has $a_n=\frac{\cos n}{n^2+e^{-n}}$. Using the inequalities
$$0\le |a_n|=\frac1{n^2+e^{-n}} \le \frac1{n^2}$$
we see that the series $\sum a_n$ is absolutely convergent.